# IntelliJ - Collapsable blocks

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, formatting

I've used Php for quiet some time and really liked/got used to the feature to collapse code blocks surrounded by curly brackets, with a click on the little plus/minus icons next to the linenumbers.
[PhpStorm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8WnO.png)

Now I'm doing a Java project with IntelliJ and would like to have this feature too. It works for certain cases like classes, functions and custom regions, but not for if/else, switch statements.
[IntelliJ without icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRdnR.png)

Already tried changing the Folding options, but without success. I know I can achieve the same result by some keyboard-shortcut, but I would like to have those little plus/minus icons next to the linenumbers.

After using the shortcut the little icons appear though. 
[IntelliJ with icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYY9U.png)

Am I missing some options or is there a plugin that can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it's shown for classes, functions, and custom regions. Please vote for this request to change default behavior: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-144819

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question if you tried to enable "code folding outline" feature in the settings, which is under **Editor** -> **General** -> **Code Folding** -> **Show code folding outline** which does what you want basically.

Comment: Sorry, yeah already tried that. Edited the question to clarify things. As @y.bedrov mentioned it only works for certain cases, but not for if/else and switch statements